# Prove that mutual information between integer and fractional parts goes to zero

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory

For a random variable $X$ with a density function $f(x),$ I want to prove that the following holds:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}I(\lfloor nX\rfloor;\{nX\})=0
$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor, \{x\}$ denote the integer and fractional parts of a real number $x$.

My attempt: I was able to prove that $\{nX\}$ converges to uniform random variable in distribution. But I couldn't use this information to prove the desired result.

Can anyone help me with this ? One can assume additional properties on $f(x)$ if needed.

Comment: It seems to me that there are two cases; $f(x) = c$ or the cardinality of the image is $\mathbb{R}$. The constant case is easy. If $n$ goes to infinity in the other case, then maybe you can use someting about the cardinalities of $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively. Just brainstorming, interesting question. Might chime in again